# Python: Search for keywords in a txt file that was converted from ebook and replace keywords.

Tags: python

The book I converted to a txt file is about 400 pages long. I want to loop through about a 1000 keywords and add a prefix to each keyword in the book. I am having trouble searching the whole book.

```
    lines = open('list.txt', 'r').read().split("\n")

    inpot = open('in.txt').read()
    fout = open('in.txt', 'w')

    def wr(lines):
        with open('in.txt', 'r') as inF:
            for line in inF:
                if lines in line:
                     fout.write(line.replace(lines, "$"+lines))


    for i in range(len(lines)):
        wr(lines[i])
```

Comment: You're opening the same file 3 times?

Comment: what kind of trouble?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're trying to achieve:

```
import os
import re

# Get keywords.
with open('list.txt', 'r') as f:
    keywords = f.read().split("\n")
    rekeywords = '(' + '|'.join(keywords) + ')'

# Write new file with '$' in front of keywords.
with open('in.txt', 'r') as f_in, open('out.txt', 'w') as f_out:
    for line in f_in:
        f_out.write(re.sub(rekeywords, r'$\1', line))

# Replace old file with new.
os.remove('in.txt')
os.rename('out.txt', 'in.txt')
```

Comment: What would be the best way change it so that only the first keyword would be changed? Is it better to use re.sub in these cases?

Comment: You can use both `re.sub('(' + keywords[0] + ')', r'$\1', line))` or the simpler `line.replace(keywords[0], '$' + keywords[0])`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

def replace_keywords(input_file, keywords):
    for line in input_file.readlines():
        tmp_line = line
        for keyword in keywords:
            i = 0
            while i >= 0:
                m = keyword.search(tmp_line, match_index)
                if m:
                    tmp_line = tmp_line[i:] + '$' + tmp_line[:i]
        yield tmp_line

with open('lines.txt', 'r') as f:
    regex_keywords = [re.compile('\\b{0}\\b'.format(k), re.I) for k in f.readlines()]

with open('output.txt', 'w') as output:
    with open('input.txt', 'r') as input:
        print >> output, '\n'.join(replace_keywords(input, regex_keywords))
```

Comment: I am gettings an error.                                                           
 while match_index >= 0:
                NameError: global name 'match_index' is not defined

Comment: Forgot to rename it to `i` when editing the code, sorry.